# Surround with capability in qt creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, code-snippets

In visual studio there is a command which you can surround a piece of a code with a for/if/try-catch/etc([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz.aspx)). 
can I do that in qt creator? how?

(I know that I can use [code snippet](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html), but I want to use "surround with..." capability).

Answer (score 3):

I agree..sure would be nice if this was built-in!
Here's how I worked around this shortfall.

**How to use it**

- select the text that needs wrapping
- use the keyboard shortcut to run a macro

**Side effect**

- mangles the clipboard

**To Create**

- Start recording a macro (tools / text editing macros)
- Control-X
- Type the left part of your wrapper
- Control-V
- Type the right part of your wrapper
- Stop recording
- Save last macro
- Assign a shortcut to the macro (tools / options / keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

To this date QtCreator doesn't have this feature.